# Auto increment for different prefixes - EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

So I have a table with Invoices. Currently the Key column is used as invoice number. It automatically increments because it is a key column, of course.

Now the application will be used by different companies in different countries. So the invoice numbering is incorrect if both of them create a invoice.

So, while in country A the latest invoice number might be 2018002345, in country B someone should be able to create a invoice with Id 201800001 and thereafter 201800002.

Of course the default `[Key]` column wouldn't work for this, I think?

Added to that, it is a good idea to have a prefix for them, so a prefix with the Country code: NL20180002345 and US2018000001. (Maybe it is possible to use the Key column when prefixes are unique?).
In a perfect situation the numbers increment +1, but if this is REALLY difficult then a solution that has a 99% probability is acceptable.

So I am looking for a correct way to handle this situation. It is an existing and in production application so out of the blue changing the Key column wouldn't be possible, migrations will be needed if changing them.

I would like to avoid the situation where I first have to call the database to retrieve the last key and then insert one incremented, that gives problems and does not scale.

The database is generated using Code-First migrations. I would prefer a solution that can be made with code-first annotations. However, there is a second project using the Database without Entity Framework, it is using Dapper. So on the other side, a MSSQL solution could be good as well?

Current entities:

**Invoice**

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public int BillingAddressId { get; set; }
    public int? OrderId { get; set; }
    public int? RefundInvoiceId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    //more properties
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PayDate { get; set; }
    public PaymentStatusEnum PaymentStatus { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BillingAddressId")]
    public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
}
```

So it is linked to an address, which is linked to a country which holds the country code.

**Address**

```
public class Address
{
    public int addressId { get; set; }
    public int countryId { get; set; }
    //more properties
    public bool validated { get; set; }
    public AddressTypeEnum addressType { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

**Country**

```
public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public double Taxpercentage { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CurrencyId")]
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is it **critical** that the invoices have no gaps? For example, can `201800001` be followed by `201800013` rather than `201800002`? _I ask since, if so, the question becomes **way** easier._

Comment: From your description I assume two countries might have invoices with the same number? If so, how you can handle this without changing key column which, as I understand, is unique?

Comment: @Evk hits on the major issue here.  You don't want to change a primary key column but you also want to have duplicate keys.  To do this requires at least changing the table to have a composite key that combines the newly non-unique invoice number with a prefix value, if not a larger redesign of the table structure

Comment: Let me clarify, yes 2 countries might have the same invoice number, that is why I think the primary key column is not the option (unless something done with prefixes can handle this). @mjwills Ideal solution would be no, no gaps, but if you have a working solution that will certainly not get duplicates then that might work.

Comment: @iamdave I want to point out there that changing the primary key column involves migrations, which is OK but it is just something to consider before posting a solution? :)

Comment: Does your table currently store the country code somewhere other than within the invoice number? Also, if an invoice were created, and then deleted, would you expect subsequent Invoices numbers to be changed to fill the gap? What if it was created and immediately deleted?

Comment: In fact, it would be helpful if you posted the DDL of your existing table.

Comment: Invoices will never be deleted, they either be cancelled/refunded (status). Simply because tax companies rather don't see gaps. Country code is stored in a linked table. I will update my answer.

Comment: You simply cannot have duplicate values within a primary key column.  Either the key or the column needs to be changed or you sacrifice the requirement to have the same invoice numbers in different countries.

Comment: When you say in a linked table, are you saying your invoice table has a foreign key to it? I might have an idea, but not until I can see the DDL and see it's possible with your current set up.

Comment: @iamdave that is fine, if another column is created it is fine, I don't mind. As long as per-country there are separated invoice numbers, yes it would be possible to have a invoice number with NL20180003 and US20180003. Apparently this is not a common scenario? Don't worry about confusion, the data is eventually separated on departments, only higher managers can see all invoices. Larnu, yes a foreign key, see update.

Comment: Leave PK as `InvoiceId` (IDENTITY column). Add `CountryId` or `CountryCode` to the `Invoice` table. This should meet your requirements (as long as you are happy with gaps in invoice IDs within a given country). A nice benefit of this is that there will **never** be duplicate invoice ids, within **or** across countries.

Comment: I was after the SQL DDL, not your object definitions in C#. :) I'm thinking this might be possible using a `DEFAULT` value and a Scalar function; so you don't have to call the table prior. It's not ideal, but it'll work; especially as the function would be run in the same Transaction, meaning that a duplicate should not be attempted to be created.

Comment: Also, where are you planning to store a value of `'GB2018000001'`? `InvoiceID` is declared as an `int`; so you can't store that in there.

Comment: Hi @Larnu well reason for this is that the database is generated using C#, so changing the column without the application knowing it would result in mis-behavior (errors that database is different then the entities). But I am looking forward to your solution anyways. Changing from int to string (varchar) is possible as long as I am then able to increment them per country.

Comment: Apparently my coffee hadn't set in, and i completely forgot that you can't pass columns values to a scalar function within a `DEFAULT` constraint. /facepalm

Comment: Haha, you need better coffee :). Perhaps you can do something with KarloX's answer? I can't seem to create a working trigger with sequence based on the countryCode :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a server-side solution, you could use an [insert trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) on your invoice table and equip the field value in your trigger code. You could use ([sequence objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql)) to generate the numbers, probably two distinct sequences for the two countries may work for you. Your invoice id field can by a nvarchar string, so your trigger code could apply the country prefix, too.

Then, on the client side, label that field with the DatabaseGenerated attribute like so:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public string InvoiceId { get; set; }
```

This instructs EF to fetch the column value (that was created in your trigger) in the same roundtrip when you insert or update that table.

**A simplified example:**

```
create table Invoice (
  Id int not null primary key identity(1,1),
  InvoiceId nvarchar(20),
  CountryId int not null
  -- etc.
)

CREATE SEQUENCE InvNo_US 
    START WITH 1000000  
    INCREMENT BY 1;  
GO  

CREATE TRIGGER TriInvoice_AI
ON Invoice AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  declare @id int, @country_id int, @seq bigint;

  DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR   
    SELECT i.Id, i.CountryId from inserted i
    ORDER BY i.Id;

  open c;
  fetch next from c into @id, @country_id;

  while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  begin
    /* TODO: At this point you may use different sequence object depending on @country_id,
       you may apply different country prefixed and maybe do other specific formatting to the InvoiceId 
       This example always just uses 'US' and doesn't take the @country_id in account at all. */
    set @seq = NEXT VALUE FOR InvNo_US;
    update Invoice set InvoiceId = 'US' + cast(@seq as nvarchar) where Id=@id;
    fetch next from c into @id, @country_id;
  end
  close c;
  deallocate c;
END
```

Test like this:

```
insert into Invoice (CountryId) values (42);
select * from Invoice;
```

Comment: Interesting! Do you have an example for the Trigger doing this?

Comment: I added an example to the aswer

Comment: Funny, In the meantime I was doing the same thing. Didn't test this now but it looks like we are on the same page here, thanks!